# Get previous object to end() of array

Tags: php

I got an array and check if `end()` exists or is empty. If it is empty I would like to get the previous object of the array. I tried using `prev()` but that didn't seem to work when applied to `end()`.

any suggestions? the array can vary in lenght and size.

Thanks for your help guys!

Some code:

```
$pagination = esc_url( get_next_posts_page_link()); // returns url with slashes
$parts = explode('/', $pagination);
//get the last item
$tag = end($parts);
if ($tag == ""){echo prev($tag); } else{echo $tag;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not apply `prev()` on the result of `end()` but on the original array as both functions are manipulating the internal array pointer of that array.

So:

```
if ($tag == ""){echo prev($parts); } else{echo $tag;}
```

**Edit:** By the way, you can also do a `trim($pagination, '/')` before you `explode` so that the last item will never be empty.

Comment: This is a more elegnat solution that PeeHaa's I believe. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) for this:

```
$theItem = array_slice($theArray, -2, 1);
```

Comment: but isn't that for fixed lenght arrays?

Comment: Nope. Because of the negative offset it doesn't matter how many items are in the array. [DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kltw61)

Comment: I see great :). Let me try to implement it :).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
<?php

    $arr = array("foo", "bar", "hi", "bye");

    echo $arr[count($arr)-2];

?>
```

`2` because `count()` starts at `1`, not `0`.

**Output**

hi

Answer (score 0):

Revere the array and use `array_pop`

```
$parts_reversed = array_reverse($parts, true);
$tag = array_pop($parts_reversed);
if ($tag == ""){echo array_pop($parts_reversed); } else{echo $tag;}
```